# Component from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla, components, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

Since the release of Joomla 3.0 Alpha last night, I wanted to try my hand at starting to convert the Joomla 2.5 component I have written to the new Joomla 3.0. I have been following all of the development convos, they said the JController, JView, and JModel would be changed to have "Legacy" after each one and that would be about all you would have to change.

I have run into the other problem, getting an error message as follows:

"**Strict Standards: Declaration of MYCOMPONENTController::display() should be compatible with that of JControllerLegacy::display()**"

I have looked an more documentation and posts and no one has come across this or talking about it, so just wanted to get it out there, and see what I need to do to fix this. Thanks all!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the answer, the function display needed one more parameter that I did not have in there. So changed from this:

```
class MYCOMPONENTController extends JControllerLegacy
{
    function display($cachable = false)
```

To this:

```
    function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false)
```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: Haha.. sorry, i was just excited. Beta 1 is looking good to me!